# Generalized Tensorflow CSV Load

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I am trying to load a large CSV file into a TensorFlow pipeline where each row represents a a flattened 256*256 image. I am trying to generalize the TensorFlow CSV files read example but am having trouble generalizing the decode_csv function to accomadate all of my columns:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

# setup text reader
file_length = file_len(filename)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)

# setup CSV decoding
record_defaults = [[0] for i in range(256*256)]
col = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)

features = tf.pack([col[i] for i in range(256*256))

print("loading, " + str(file_length) + " line(s)\n")
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

  # start populating filename queue
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(file_length):
    # retrieve a single instance
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
    print(example, label)

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
  print("\ndone loading")
```

However I am getting the error

```
TypeError: Expected list for 'values' argument to 'Pack' Op, not <generator object <genexpr> at 0x12447e2d0>
```

How do I generalize the col1,...colN section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part. tf.pack can take a list argument so there is no need to to separate output of tf.decode_csv into different cols. It can simply be done with

```
col = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.pack(col)
```